# How to over write Tomcat's xml file properties from java struts 1.1 application. Specifically maxPostSIze

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, struts, struts1

I am trying to upload a file through my JAVA Struts 1.1 Application. Using the Tomcat Server. 
The problem I was facing was : file size was greater than the default size of the Tomcat allowed size. So we need to change the "maxPostSize" parameter of server.xml

After changing the maxPostSize and the connectionTimeout in Server.xml, the issue is resolved. However what if we do not have the permission to make changes to server.xml

Is there a way around for this through Java code. Any way by which we can overwrite the "maxPostSize" parameter of server.xml
any way I can cofigure my application to ignore the Tomcat Size and take the specified size limit.

Please Help!

Comment: can u paste the snippet from server.xml ?

Comment: Server Snippet I want to overwrite in java is : 
server.xml in {Tomcat installation folder}\ conf \ 

for 8MB => 8*1024*1204 =8388608

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="8388608" />

Answer (score 0):

Please check your controller (in struts-config) has something
like this (I think it's optional actually),

```
<controller
maxFileSize="300K" />
```

change size and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: This does not work. No Help after adding this part to my struts-config

Comment: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:429)
 at org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.java:195)
 at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:445)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:798)
Error LOg